# Poor probability results for SVM text classification

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

I'm fairly new to machine learning technologies and I'm using sklearn and SVC to perform date classification on texts as apart of a project, but I'm getting incredibly low probabiltiy scores.

I have a corpus of 13 texts all authored at different dates ranging from 598 to 1358 (which I use as classes) stored in a train and test file directory, I use a CountVectoriser and TfidfTransformer to prepare the data and pickle my results for later use:

```
src = "../data/datasets/pickledWordLists/"

corpus = []

for filename in os.listdir(src):
    with (open(os.path.join(src, filename), "rb")) as openfile:
        while True:
            try:
                text = pickle.load(openfile)
                text = ' '.join(word for word in text)
                corpus.append(text)
            except EOFError:
                break

src = "../data/datasets/TestsPickled/"

for filename in os.listdir(src):
    with (open(os.path.join(src, filename), "rb")) as openfile:
        while True:
            try:
                text = pickle.load(openfile)
                text = ' '.join(word for word in text)
                corpus.append(text)
            except EOFError:
                break

vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
vectorizer.fit(corpus)
vector = vectorizer.transform(corpus)

tfidf_transformer = TfidfTransformer()
vector = tfidf_transformer.fit_transform(vector)

with open('../data/datasets/labeledData/training/train_matrices/corpus.pickle', 'wb') as handle:
    pickle.dump(vector, handle)
```

After this I load it back in:

```
 train_sparse = []
 with open('../data/datasets/labeledData/training/train_matrices/corpus.pickle', 'rb') as handle:
     train_sparse = pickle.load(handle)

 train_set = np.array(train_sparse.toarray()[0:9])
 test_set = np.array(train_sparse.toarray()[10:14])

 labels = [1028, 1107, 1358, 598, 707, 875, 884, 890, 988]
```

I then fit a SVC with the training data and class labels:

```
clf = SVC(kernel='linear', C=100, cache_size=300, class_weight='balanced', coef0=10.0,
decision_function_shape='ovo', degree=10, gamma='auto',
max_iter=-1, probability=True, random_state=None, shrinking=False,
tol=1, verbose=False)

clf.fit(train_set, labels)
```

Experimenting with the fitted SVC, and to get some confidence I test it on one of the examples it was **actually trained on** (clf.predict([train_sparse.toarray()[6]], class 884) expecting a close to 1.0 probabiltiy score for that class. I actually get a very poor result with an incorrect classification.

```
Actual Class: 884
Predicted Class: [988]
Class: 1028 probability: 0.13680521863292022 %
Class: 1107 probability: 0.1372151835630488 %
Class: 1358 probability: 0.09314753496099398 %
Class: 598 probability: 0.11216304253012621 %
Class: 707 probability: 0.07705449472997644 %
Class: 875 probability: 0.07702437742491991 %
Class: 884 probability: 0.11694844959109225 %
Class: 890 probability: 0.12739816653603753 %
Class: 988 probability: 0.1222435320308847 %
```

Other attempts produce simmilar results:

```
Actual Class: 890
Predicted Class: [890]
Class: 1028 probability: 0.13682366473176108 %
Class: 1107 probability: 0.1372180833047104 %
Class: 1358 probability: 0.09312179238345174 %
Class: 598 probability: 0.11286567433780788 %
Class: 707 probability: 0.07636519076484871 %
Class: 875 probability: 0.07712682059152805 %
Class: 884 probability: 0.1169118710112273 %
Class: 890 probability: 0.12735823672708854 %
Class: 988 probability: 0.12220866614757639 %
```

Is there anything I can do to get these probabiltiy scores up (or down)? rather than sitting around the 10% - 12% mark for everything I try it on? I tested this on a seperate english language corpus; 9 texts, all about the same size ranging in dates from 900 - 1600, this was giving me very simmilar scores. I need a probability score because part of my project is to see whether a text can be roughly dated based on a range of class simmilarity scores from various dates.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you're using a linear kernel and not say, rbf?

Comment: I use linear because the majority of text classification examples I've seen are using linear, using rbf or polynominal kernel's don't appear to have any valuable impact on my results (a percent here or there).

Comment: Have you tried a lower penalty $C$?

Comment: I have, C=1 and C=100 in my case produce the same results

Comment: They make slight diferences when using 'rbf' or 'poly' kernels, but again, not particuarly valuable changes

Comment: First, please look at how [SVM calculates probabilities](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/svm.html#scores-and-probabilities) in which the class predicted from the SVM may not have the highest probability

Comment: Secondly, you said you have 13 texts and 9 classes. This seems like too less of data to be making any meaningful prediction in my opinion.

Comment: Thank you, are there any good techniques for making predictions on very limited datasets such as mine that you could recommend?